# Grafana variable regex returns no results when using MongoDB source

Tags: regex, grafana, grafana-variable

I am creating a variable in Grafana from a mongoDB query.
Currently my query returns an array of items in the format of:

```
name="Bob Hansen", id="8051240138eb2ea033aa21f3"
name="John Doe", id="4051240138eb2ea033aa21f3"
...
```

Now I am trying to use regex to extract the two key/value pairs like described here: https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/v9.0/variables/filter-variables-with-regex/#filter-and-modify-using-named-text-and-value-capture-groups

I have the following regex:

```
/name="(?<text>[^"]+)|id="(?<value>[^"]+)/g
```

But grafana keeps returning no values, unless I remove the regex :(

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use alteration.

Alteration in your regex means, that once first branch is matched, second part is not checked.

Correct expression for this case will be

```
name="(?<text>[^"]+)", id="(?<value>[^"]+)
```

Demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/OoaaVp/1).